# Why is polonium tetrafluoride non-existent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides

I learnt that the group 16 elements can form halides, but with the exception that polonium cannot form a tetrahalide with fluorine.

However, I thought that it was possible. This is because the electronegativity difference between polonium and fluorine is very high since polonium is a metal and fluorine is a highly electronegative atom and so should be able to form a salt.

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Polonium in it's +4 oxidation state would mainly form covalent compounds as removing the first 4 electrons (sum of first 4 ionization energies) would be very high. Thus, if $\ce{PoF4}$ were to exist, it would have to be a covalent halide.

Comment: but isn't polonium a metal, also the electronegative difference between Po and Fl is very high, so ionic character has to be high right?

Comment: It is hard to characterize polonium compounds due of its radioactivity.

Comment: @Anir is right - compounds on higher ox. states are molecular in spite of significant ionic component in bonding.

Answer (score 5):

Before going into details, let me state [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium_hexafluoride):

> $\ce{^{208}PoF6}$ was probably successfully synthesised via the same
> reaction (passing fluorine gas over $\ce{^{208}Po}$) in 1960 where a
> volatile polonium fluoride was produced, but it was not fully
> characterized before **it underwent radiolysis and decomposed to
> polonium tetrafluoride**.

Even attempts were made to dissolve polonium metal in hydrofluoric acid but no fluoride salts were isolated as a free salt as they radiolysed and decomposed. According to this [1961 paper](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4034029):

> Although no fluoride salts of $\ce{Po}$ have been isolated, $\ce{Po}$
> is quite soluble in $\ce{HF}$. Solutions containing 2  curies of
> $\ce{Po}$ per ml of $\ce{1 N HF}$ are reported to be unsaturated.
> Attempts to prepare a volatile fluoride by reaction with $\ce{F2}$ gas or
> with liquid $\ce{BF3}$ have been unsuccessful. However recent work with $\pu{1
>  mg}$ of $\ce{^{208}Po}$ indicated the formation of a volatile $\ce{Po}$ compound,
> **which decomposed before it could be isolated**.

Polonium tetrafluoride is very difficult to isolate as it is seen to form either a complex or oxidize/decompose radiolytically. Also, bringing analytical data on such compounds is hard as they are produced in minute amounts possible in the range of micrograms. Below is a text from [this e-book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8qePsa3V8GQC&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=polonium%20difluoride&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q=polonium%20difluoride&f=false) <sup>1</sup>

> A white solid possibly polonium tetrafluoride is obtained by treating
> polonium hydroxide/tetrachloride with aqueous dilute hydrofluoric
> acid. Treating this solid suspension in sulfur dioxide yields a bluish
> grey product (possibly $\ce{PoF2}$) which quickly reverts back to the
> solid on standing owing to radiolytic oxidation. **The solubility of
> $\ce{Po(IV)}$ increases with the concentration of hydrofluoric acid
> indicating a complex formation**
>
> There has been unsuccessful attempts to make volatile hexafluoride by
> passing fluorine to $\ce{^{210}Po}$ but recently a fluoride has been
> made with $\ce{^{208}Po}$ plated on platinum. This product appers to
> be quite stable in vapor phase but on cooling, a nonvolatile compound
> is formed possibly polonium tetrafluoride resulting from radioactive
> decomposition. **Analytical data are not recorded for any polonium
> fluorides owing to difficulty of determining fluoride ion at microgram
> level.**

**Reference**

1. Advances in Inorganic Chemistry and Radiochemistry, Academic Press, **1962**
2. https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4367751/4367751.PDF

Comment: Also note PoCl4 is known - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polonium_tetrachloride With intensely radioactive elements especially one needs to carefully separate "not known due to some chemical instability" with "not known because nobody has observed it yet"